# Can I invalidate a Symfony2 form?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an issue in that a Symfony2 form can pass validation but still generate a Doctrine2 exception caused by a unique constraint when the form is submitted.  I can catch this PDOException, but what I want to do is invalidate the form and set a form error indicating that a particular attribute of the entity is a duplicate.  The code I have is:

```
    $entity = new Tag();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new \Acme\AdminBundle\Form\Tag(), $entity);
    $form->bindRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        try {
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tag_edit', array('id' => $entity->getTagId())));
        } catch( ORM\PDOException $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() === '23000') {
                    // What do I do here??
            }
        }

    }
    return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [UniqueEntity annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html).
If you use it, you won't need the try/catch block, because a check will be performed before an insert is even attempted.